# Multi language website symfony3 routing issue with locale and wildcards

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-3.1

I have a multilanguage site, where I have the following issues with routing and locale:

I have the home routing:

```
@Route("/", name="homepage")
```

And I have another page with locale and wildcard:

```
@Route("/{_locale}/{_offerValue}",requirements={"_locale":"en|de","_offerValue":"option1|option2"}, defaults={"_locale":"en"}, name="offer")
```

The issue is, that now instead the homepage I have also the offer coming up, which I understand as the _locale and _offerValue are optional.

How can this be resolved?

Thank you

Comment: The router resolver will take the first route which matches with the request. Check your routing declaration, and put the "/" route before your other route. Btw, your second route will only be  called on "/en" or "/de". 
If you call "/", so homepage route will be called first.

Comment: Partialy resolved my problem.